# VBScript purge file not deleting specified files

Tags: vbscript

I have a simple purging script written in VBScript which compares the difference between a specified file's creation date and today's date and should then delete it if the date is greater than a certain number of days.

I have also included a logging mechanism, which writes the date and the deleted files to a text file.

I run the script under the command prompt (as Administrator) using the wscript command. I have tried cscript also.

The problem: While the log file is produced and contains the headers, the files themselves are not deleted and consequently there is no deletion data in the log. I am not terribly familiar with VBScript, but the code is reasonably intuitive. After numerous tweaks and attempts at modifications, the darn thing still will not act as it should!

```
On Error Resume Next

Set oFileSys = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objLog = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\log.txt")
sRoot = "C:\file_folder"            'Path root to look for files
today = Date
nMaxFileAge = 7             'Files older than this (in days) will be deleted

DeleteFiles(sRoot)

Function DeleteFiles(ByVal sFolder)
    Set oFolder = oFileSys.GetFolder(sFolder)
    Set aFiles = oFolder.Files
    Set aSubFolders = oFolder.SubFolders

    objLog.WriteLine "Purging Log"
    objLog.WriteLine "Dated " & today

    For Each file in aFiles
        dFileCreated = FormatDateTime(file.DateCreated, "2")
        If DateDiff("d", dFileCreated, today) > nMaxFileAge Then
            file.Delete(True)
            objLog.WriteLine "The file named '" & file & "' was successfully deleted."
        End If
    Next

    For Each folder in aSubFolders
        DeleteFiles(folder.Path)
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Try `oFileSys.DeleteFile file.Path`, note when you do that, `file` will be kinda borked, because the file no longer exists, and you may be unable to run that `WriteLine`.

Comment: Why do you have both **oFileSys** and **objFSO** set to a new **FileSystemObject**? Surely you only need one?

Comment: Thanks!!! I got it working. I put the `Writeline` segment above Havenard's suggested deletion code and it wrote to the file and deleted everything. Thanks for your help!